# Egyptian fractions of the form `2/n` with smallest sum of denominators

Tags: optimization, egyptian-fractions

I realize this has been asked for the more general $p/q$ case; however, I am restricting myself to the case of $p=2$ and $q$ is odd (see the [Rhind Mathematical Papyrus 2/n table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhind_Mathematical_Papyrus_2/n_table)).

It's easy to show that any fraction of the form $2/(2N+1)$ can be written as the fraction

$$\frac{2}{2N+1} = \frac{1}{N+1} + \frac{1}{(N+1)(2N+1)}$$

which appears to be optimal for prime numbers. However, I was trying to express the problem as an optimization problem (KKT) and am not getting a solution. I'm not sure if I'm formulating it correctly, or something else. The problem can be formulated as

$$f(x) = x_1 + x_2$$
$$g(x) = \frac{2}{2N+1} - \frac{1}{x_1} - \frac{1}{x_2} = 0$$
$$h(x) = [ 2-x_1 , x_1+1 - x_2 ]^T \le 0$$

This means the Lagrangian is

$$\mathcal{L} = x_1 + x_2 - \lambda \left[ (2N+1)(x_1+x_2)-2x_1x_2 \right] - \mu_1(2-x_1)-\mu_2(x_1+1 - x_2)$$

So the KKT conditions are

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_1} = \lambda (2 n - 2 x_2 + 1 )+1+\mu_1-\mu_2=0$$

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_2} = \lambda  (2 n-2 x_1+1) + 1 +\mu_2 = 0$$

$$\mu_1 ( 2 - x_1 ) =0$$

$$\mu_1 \ge 0$$

$$\mu_2 ( x_1 + 1 - x_2 ) =0$$

$$\mu_2 \ge 0$$

$$\frac{2}{2N+1} =\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{x_2} = 0$$

Solving for $x_1$ and $x_2$

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\mu_1>0 & \mu_2>0 & x_1=2 & x_2=3 & \mathrm{violates\ constraint} \\ \hline
\mu_1>0 & \mu_2=0 & x_1=2 & x_2=6 & \mathrm{correct} \\ \hline
\mu_1=0 & \mu_2>0 & x_1=n + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2+4n+4n^2} & x_2=x_1+1 & \mathrm{not\ a\ solution\ over\ the\ natural\ numbers} \\ \hline
\mu_1=0 & \mu_2=0 & x_1=2n+1 & x_2=x_1 & \mathrm{violates\ constraint} \\ \hline
\end{array}

So is this problem not suited for KKT? Have I done something incorrect?

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Karush-Kuhn-Tucker is for continuous optimization.  Here you want $x_1$ and $x_2$ to be natural numbers. KKT has nothing to say about this.

Comment: Is there another optimization technique I can use?